# Apache FOP: How to set base URL for accessing external resource using relative path

Tags: apache-fop

In my .xsl file I am using external graphics like this
`<fo:external-graphic width="90pt" height="29pt" src="url(xsl/logo.jpg)"/>`

But image is not getting loaded in the generated PDF and I get this error in console.
`[ERROR] Error while creating area : Error with image URL: xsl\logo.jpg (The system cannotfind the path specified) and no base URL is specified`

How do I solve this issue? I guess setting the base URL will do. But how to set the base URL? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a solution from this link
http://groups.yahoo.com/group/XSL-FO/message/6116

set base dir using Java code

```
ServletContext servletContext = getServletConfig().getServletContext();

String appPath = servletContext.getRealPath(""); //root of web app
org.apache.fop.configuration.Configuration.put("baseDir",appPath);
```

This worked for me.
Please post if you know any better solution.

Answer (score 3):

I am using Apache FOP 1.1 Ver.

```
    fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();
    // for image base URL : images from Resource path of project
    String serverPath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
    fopFactory.setBaseURL(serverPath);
    // for fonts base URL :  .ttf from Resource path of project
    fopFactory.getFontManager().setFontBaseURL(serverPath);
```

I added all images and required font font files in resource director of my project.
It is working fine for me.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and this only works for me in the version 0.95 of fop.
SetBaseUrl is ignored in version 1.0

Answer (score 0):

Solution for versions 1.0, 1.1 :
In fop 1.0 and 1.1 method setBaseURL() does not work correctly with local files, so you can use method setURIResolveri and write your implementation of interface URIResolver.

1.Add in uses
    import javax.xml.transform.URIResolver;

2.Add in mainClass

```
 private static class LocalResolver implements URIResolver {
         private String BaseFolder; 
            @Override
            public Source resolve(String href, String base) throws TransformerException {
             File f = new File(BaseFolder + "\\" + href);
             if (f.exists())
             return new StreamSource(f);
                     else
                      throw new TransformerException("File " + f.getAbsolutePath() +" not found!");         
            }

         public LocalResolver(String BaseFolder) {
           this.BaseFolder = BaseFolder;   
         }

     }
```

Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, out);

3.Add before call   transformer.transform(src, res) this:

```
fop.getUserAgent().setURIResolver(new LocalResolver("C:\\Users\\photon\\Downloads\\fop-1.1-bin\\fop-1.1"));
```

Comment: Egor could you please add some documentation?